# How to find out if a Twitter user has more than one Twitter account and view them

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to see if a Twitter user has other Twitter accounts and verify they are their accounts?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

Twitter allows adding multiple accounts in their web and mobile apps. AFAIK, the accounts are completely independent and not *linked* in any manner. I don't think Twitter would do the linking without informing users about it. Even if the accounts are linked in their databases for security reasons, the information isn't publicly available.